# How to escape a lot of included div tags?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I make profile page in vue/cli 4 / Bootstrap 4.3 app like:

```
    <div class="page_content_content col-sm-12 col-md-8 p-2 m-0 mx-auto">

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <i :class="'i_link '+getHeaderIcon('profile')"></i><strong>Profile</strong>
            </div>

            <div class="card-body card-block">

                <div class="block_2columns_md m-3"> <!-- name -->

                    <div class="key_values_rows_label_13 m-0 p-0">
                        <label class="col-form-label" for="name">Name:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="key_values_rows_value_13 m-0 p-0">

                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                <i :class="'i_link '+getHeaderIcon('users')"></i>
                            </div>
                            <input
                                    type='text'
                                    v-model="userProfileRow.name"
                                    name="name"
                                    id="name"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    readonly="readonly"
                            >
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div> <!-- <div class="block_2columns_md m-0"> name -->

                <div class="block_2columns_md m-3"> <!-- email -->

                    <div class="key_values_rows_label_13 m-0 p-0">
                        <label class="col-form-label" for="email">Email:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="key_values_rows_value_13 m-0 p-0">

                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                <i :class="'i_link '+getHeaderIcon('email')"></i>
                            </div>
                            <input
                                    type='email'
                                    v-model="userProfileRow.email"
                                    name="email"
                                    id="email"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    readonly="readonly"
                            >
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div> <!-- <div class="block_2columns_md m-0"> email -->

                <div class="block_2columns_md m-3"> <!-- userGroups -->
                    <div class="key_values_rows_label_13 m-0 p-0">
                        <label class="col-form-label" for="email">Access groups:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="key_values_rows_value_13 m-0 p-0">

                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                <i :class="'i_link '+getHeaderIcon('has_access')"></i>
                            </div>

                            <ul v-if="userGroups.length">
                                <li v-for="nextUserGroup in userGroups" :key="nextUserGroup.group_id" >
                                    {{ nextUserGroup.group_name }}
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div> <!-- <div class="block_2columns_md m-0"> userGroups -->

                <div class="block_2columns_md m-3"> <!-- first_name -->
                    <div class="key_values_rows_label_13 m-0 p-0">
                        <label class="col-form-label" for="first_name">First name:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="key_values_rows_value_13 m-0 p-0">
                        <input
                                type='email'
                                v-model="userProfileRow.first_name"
                                name="first_name"
                                id="first_name"
                                class="form-control"
                                readonly="readonly"
                        >
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- <div class="block_2columns_md m-0"> first_name -->


                <div class="block_2columns_md m-3"> <!-- last_name -->
                    <div class="key_values_rows_label_13 m-0 p-0">
                        <label class="col-form-label" for="last_name">Last name:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="key_values_rows_value_13 m-0 p-0">
                        <input
                                type='email'
                                v-model="userProfileRow.last_name"
                                name="last_name"
                                id="last_name"
                                class="form-control"
                                readonly="readonly"
                        >
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- <div class="block_2columns_md m-0"> last_name -->


                <div class="block_2columns_md m-3"> <!-- status -->
                    <div class="key_values_rows_label_13 m-0 p-0">
                        <label class="col-form-label" for="status">Status:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="key_values_rows_value_13 m-0 p-0">
                        <input
                                type='email'
                                v-model="status_label"
                                name="status"
                                id="status"
                                class="form-control"
                                readonly="readonly"
                        >
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- <div class="block_2columns_md m-0"> status -->


                <div class="block_2columns_md m-3"> <!-- phone -->
                    <div class="key_values_rows_label_13 m-0 p-0">
                        <label class="col-form-label" for="phone">Phone:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="key_values_rows_value_13 m-0 p-0">
                        <input
                                type='email'
                                v-model="userProfileRow.phone"
                                name="phone"
                                id="phone"
                                class="form-control"
                                readonly="readonly"
                        >
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- <div class="block_2columns_md m-0"> phone -->

                ...


            </div> <!-- <div class="card-body card-block"> -->


            <div class="row_content_left_aligned p-3">
                <fieldset class="blocks">
                    <legend class="blocks">Skills&nbsp;</legend>
                    <div class="table-responsive table--no-card ">
                        <table class="table table-borderless table-striped table-earning" >
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Skill</th>
                                <th>Rating</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <tbody>
                            <tr v-for="nextUserSkill in userSkills" :key="nextUserSkill.skill_id" v-show="nextUserSkill.rating">
                                <td class="text-left">
                                    {{ nextUserSkill.skill_name }}
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-left">{{ getDictionaryLabel(nextUserSkill.rating, userSkillsLabels) }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>

            </div>


            <div class="row_content_left_aligned p-3">
                <fieldset class="blocks">
                    <legend class="blocks">Assigned tasks&nbsp;</legend>
                    <div class="table-responsive table--no-card ">
                        <table class="table table-borderless table-striped table-earning" >

                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Task</th>
                                <th>Your Role</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <tbody>
                            <tr v-for="nextTaskAssignedToUser in tasksAssignedToUser" :key="nextTaskAssignedToUser.id" >
                                <td class="text-left">
                                    <router-link :to="{ name: 'taskDetails', params: { slug: nextTaskAssignedToUser.task_slug }  }" class="a_link" target="_blank">
                                        {{ nextTaskAssignedToUser.task_name }}
                                    </router-link>
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-left">
                                    <i :class="'i_link '+getHeaderIcon('description')" :title="nextTaskAssignedToUser.description"></i>{{ nextTaskAssignedToUser.user_task_type_name }}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>

                        </table>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>

            </div>

            <div class="card-footer m-0 p-0">
                <div class="form-row m-1" style="justify-content: flex-end;">
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-3">
                        <i :class="'i_link '+getHeaderIcon('cancel')"></i>Reset
                    </button>
                    <router-link :to="{ name: 'profileEditor' }" class="btn btn-success btn-sm m-3 ml-4 mr-4">
                        <i :class="'i_link '+getHeaderIcon('edit')"></i>Edit
                    </router-link>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div> <!-- <div class="card"> -->

    </div> <!-- page_content_content -->

</div> <!-- page_content_container -->
```

and it looks like I expect, the only thing I dislike a lot of included “div” tags.
And complicated debugging with it. Can you give a hint how better to deal it? I know a way for v-for listings to use “ul”, “li” tags.

What else can be aplied ?

**MODIFIED :**
After some tests made next layout of my profile editor :

```
<template>
    <article class="page_content_container">

        <div class="page_content_content col-sm-12 col-md-8 p-2 m-0 mx-auto">


            <vue-tabs
                    active-tab-color="#224A37"
                    active-text-color="white"
                    v-model="active_tab"
            >

                <v-tab title="Details">
                    <ValidationObserver
                            ref="registerObserverForm"
                            v-slot="{handleSubmit}"
                    >
                        <form class="register" @submit.prevent="handleSubmit(onSubmit)">

                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <i :class="'i_link '+getHeaderIcon('profile')"></i><strong>Profile Editor</strong>
                                </div>

                                <div class="card-body card-block">

                                    <dl class="block_2columns_md m-3"> <!-- name -->

                                        <dt class="key_values_rows_label_13 m-0 p-0">
                                            <label class="col-form-label" for="name">Name:</label>
                                        </dt>
                                        <dd class="key_values_rows_value_13 m-0 p-0">

                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <i :class="'i_link '+getHeaderIcon('users')"></i>
                                                </div>
                                                <input
                                                        type='text'
                                                        v-model="userProfileRow.name"
                                                        name="name"
                                                        id="name"
                                                        class="form-control"
                                                        readonly="readonly"
                                                >
                                            </div>

                                        </dd>

                                    </dl> <!-- <div class="block_2columns_md m-0"> name -->

                                    <dl class="block_2columns_md m-3"> <!-- email -->

                                        <dt class="key_values_rows_label_13 m-0 p-0">
                                            <label class="col-form-label" for="email">Email:</label>
                                        </dt>
                                        <dd class="key_values_rows_value_13 m-0 p-0">

                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <i :class="'i_link '+getHeaderIcon('email')"></i>
                                                </div>
                                                <input
                                                        type='email'
                                                        v-model="userProfileRow.email"
                                                        name="email"
                                                        id="email"
                                                        class="form-control"
                                                        readonly="readonly"
                                                >
                                            </div>

                                        </dd>

                                    </dl> <!-- <div class="block_2columns_md m-0"> email -->


                                    <dl class="block_2columns_md m-3"> <!-- userGroups -->
                                        <!--                        userGroups::{{ userGroups }}-->
                                        <dt class="key_values_rows_label_13 m-0 p-0">
                                            <label class="col-form-label" for="email">Access groups:</label>
                                        </dt>
                                        <dd class="key_values_rows_value_13 m-0 p-0">

                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <i :class="'i_link '+getHeaderIcon('has_access')"></i>
                                                </div>

                                                <ul>
                                                    <li v-for="nextUserGroup in userGroups" :key="nextUserGroup.group_id">
                                                        <td class="text-left">
                                                            {{ nextUserGroup.group_name }}
                                                        </td>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>

                                            </div>

                                        </dd>

                                    </dl> <!-- <div class="block_2columns_md m-0"> userGroups -->


                                </div> <!-- <div class="card-body card-block"> -->


                                    <fieldset class="blocks row_content_left_aligned">
                                        <legend class="blocks">Skills&nbsp;</legend>
                                        <div class="table-responsive table-wrapper-for-data-listing ">
                                            <table class="table table-borderless table-striped table-data-listing">
                                                <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Skill</th>
                                                    <th>Rating</th>
                                                </tr>
                                                </thead>

                                                <tbody>
                                                <tr v-for="nextUserSkill in userSkills" :key="nextUserSkill.skill_id" v-show="nextUserSkill.rating">
                                                    <td class="text-left">
                                                        {{ nextUserSkill.skill_name }}
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="text-left">{{ getDictionaryLabel(nextUserSkill.rating, userSkillsLabels) }}</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </fieldset>


                                <section class="card-footer m-0 p-0">
                                    <div class="form-row m-1" style="justify-content: flex-end;">
                                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-3">
                                            <i :class="'i_link '+getHeaderIcon('cancel')"></i>Reset
                                        </button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm m-3 ml-4 mr-4">
                                            <i :class="'i_link '+getHeaderIcon('save')"></i>Edit
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </section>

                            </div> <!-- <div class="card"> -->

                        </form>
                    </ValidationObserver>
```

What do you think about using
article - as root tag
dl, dt, dd tags - for pair of label/control wrapper
fieldset - when I need to show some sublisting below of editor form
section - in block of Cancel/Submit buttons
ul, li - some data in v-for circle

?

Thanks!

Comment: Which part of the code would you like to change as listings? I can't find any identical element or elements that are siblings that you can make use of the loop and `li` element. For me, I only use `li` if I have identical elements which I can just loop rather than creating multiple `div`. e.g. image wrapper for carousel slides. Other than that, your pasted codes is incomplete, which makes it look confusing. You don't have closing tags in the `.card-body`, `.card`, and `.page_content_content`.

Comment: I modified topic code : it has more 10 columns in view pages and 2 listings below. Sure, all tags are closed. I search some good style way of not using alot of included div.

Comment: How this page looks like for me : https://prnt.sc/q855cb, https://prnt.sc/q855pr

Comment: Any ideas as for topic?

Comment: Sorry, just got the time to answer. You can check it below. Thanks

Comment: Pls, look at MODIFIED

Comment: Also I think @Wei is wright in other post : there is a sense to use only most common tags

Comment: If your goal is using common tags, IMO `ul` and `li` is much common in the wild being used than `dl` and `dt`. But that still depends on you, I just made your code shorter in my answer than doing a repetitive element wrapper with class `block_2columns_md m-3` and other `div` s which make's your code longer.

Comment: you just pass the props to the element during loop, then you can already reuse a block of html element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, this is just a quick sample so I didn't put much detail in the html (e.g. loop function etc.), but you can check the comments in the tags, and that should do the job.

```
<div class="page_content_content col-sm-12 col-md-8 p-2 m-0 mx-auto">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <i :class="'i_link '+getHeaderIcon('profile')"></i><strong>Profile</strong>
        </div>

        <div class="block_2columns_md m-3"> 
            <!-- or you can remove the div wrapper above and move the class to the ul element -->
            <ul>
                <!-- Your for loop function here -->
                <li>
                    <div class="key_values_rows_label_13 m-0 p-0">
                        <label class="col-form-label" for="{{variable}}">{{variable}}</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="key_values_rows_value_13 m-0 p-0">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <!-- Place condition here if this loop has icon specified show this element -->
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                <i :class="'i_link '+getHeaderIcon({{variable}})"></i>
                            </div>
                                <!-- condition end -->

                            <!-- Another condition: If this loop is NOT list show input -->
                            <input
                                    type='text'
                                    v-model="{{variable}}"
                                    name="{{variable}}"
                                    id="{{variable}}"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    readonly="readonly"
                            >
                            <!-- else -->
                            <ul v-if="userGroups.length">
                                <li v-for="nextUserGroup in userGroups" :key="nextUserGroup.group_id" >
                                    {{ nextUserGroup.group_name }}
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- condition end -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <!-- Your for loop end function here -->
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- <div class="block_2columns_md m-0"> name -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

it use class text to control the style by css in bootstrap most situation.
so you can use another tags like `<xxx class='col-sm-12'></xxx>`,it'll be work fine.
but,when other one look this html code will confuse.

so i suggest you to follow the standard tag `div`.